# How to use Bitbucket webhooks to interface with a local Jenkins server? I'm getting a 404 error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I'm having trouble getting a push to a bitbucket repo to trigger a multi-branch-pipeline build on my Jenkins server. My Jenkins server is running on a public IP address and exposed via my firewall on a port. I am using Jenkins version 2.176.3

On the Jenkins side, I created a multi-branch pipeline and specified the bitbucket repo. I can invoke the pipeline build manually just fine.

On the bitbucket side, I created a webhook and point to my Jenkins server with the URL of the form:

http://my-ip-address:port/bitbucket-hook/

When I do a git push to the repo, I see bitbucket trying to calling the Jenkins server, but it is failing with a 404 error.

Is the URL format correct? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to debug it by e.g. using `curl` from the computer outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For a multi-branch pipeline you need to use a webhook URL of the form:

http://my-ip-address:port/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify

See:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000051112-Bitbucket-Webhooks-Troubleshooting